# <rich:tree> Example reRender not working Richfaces 3.3.4 final

Tags: jsf, tree, richfaces, rerender

i'm using Richfaces 3.3.4 final with JSF 1.2 on a SAP NetWeaver AS 7.31.

Now im facing some Issues with dynamically showing selected Nodes from a rich:tree in a h:outputText. The selectedNodeListener is invoked correctly and the Name of the Node is saved in a String, but my h:outputText only refreshes on Page Refresh and not on Selection like in the Example from the Showcases(http://showcase-rf3.richfaces.org/richfaces/tree.jsf?tab=model&cid=26981).

Does anyone know if this is a common Issue with the above Setup or am I just missing something? As far as I know SAP NetWeaver isnt in the List of supported Servers but its JEE5 compliant. Could this be the Reason?

I simplified the Example from the Richfaces Showcases to reproduce the Problem in a small Environment. Here is some Code:

SimpleTreeBean.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Iterator;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Map;  

import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlTree;  
import org.richfaces.event.NodeSelectedEvent;  
import org.richfaces.model.TreeNode;  
import org.richfaces.model.TreeNodeImpl;  

public class SimpleTreeBean {  
    private TreeNode rootNode = null;  
    private List<String> selectedNodeChildren = new ArrayList<String>();  

    private String nodeTitle;  


    private void loadTree() {  
            rootNode = new TreeNodeImpl();  
            TreeNodeImpl rt = new TreeNodeImpl();  
            rt.setData("Root");  
            rootNode.addChild(1, rt);  
            for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){  
                TreeNodeImpl child = new TreeNodeImpl();  
                child.setData("Child "+i);  
                rt.addChild(i, child);  
            }  
    }  

    public void processSelection(NodeSelectedEvent event) {  
        HtmlTree tree = (HtmlTree) event.getComponent();  
        nodeTitle = (String) tree.getRowData();  
        selectedNodeChildren.clear();  
        TreeNode currentNode = tree.getModelTreeNode(tree.getRowKey());  
        if (currentNode.isLeaf()) {  
            selectedNodeChildren.add((String) currentNode.getData());  
        } else {  
            Iterator<Map.Entry<Object, TreeNode>> it = currentNode  
                    .getChildren();  
            while (it != null && it.hasNext()) {  
                Map.Entry<Object, TreeNode> entry = it.next();  
                selectedNodeChildren.add(entry.getValue().getData().toString());  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    public TreeNode getTreeNode() {  
        if (rootNode == null) {  
            loadTree();  
        }  

        return rootNode;  
    }  

    public String getNodeTitle() {  
        return nodeTitle;  
    }  

    public void setNodeTitle(String nodeTitle) {  
        this.nodeTitle = nodeTitle;  
    }  
}
```

test.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>  
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>  
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>  
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>  

<html>  
<head>  
<title>TestTree</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<f:view>  
 <h:form>      
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" columnClasses="col1,col2">  

            <rich:tree style="width:300px" nodeSelectListener="#{simpleTreeBean.processSelection}"   
                reRender="selectedNode" ajaxSubmitSelection="true"  switchType="client"  
                value="#{simpleTreeBean.treeNode}" var="item" ajaxKeys="#{null}">  
            </rich:tree>  

            <h:outputText escape="false" value="Selected Node: #{simpleTreeBean.nodeTitle}" id="selectedNode" />  

        </h:panelGrid>  
    </h:form>  
</f:view>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Important Part of faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<faces-config  
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"  
    version="1.2">  
    <managed-bean>  
        <managed-bean-name>simpleTreeBean</managed-bean-name>  
        <managed-bean-class>  
            com.realcore.web.beans.SimpleTreeBean  
        </managed-bean-class>  
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>  
    </managed-bean>  

</faces-config>  
<</faces-config>/faces-config>
```

Additionally there are some Validators and Converters in my faces-config too. But I think this isnt important for this Problem.

And here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">  
    <display-name>SstSapWEB</display-name>  
    <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>  
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>  
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>  
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>  
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  

    <!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->  
    <context-param>  
        <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>  
        <param-value>enable</param-value>  
    </context-param>  
    <!-- Defining and mapping the RichFaces filter -->  
    <filter>  
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>  
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>  
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>  
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>  
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>  
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>  
    </filter-mapping>  

    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

This simple Example isnt working too.

I don't know how to fix or workaround this Issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just in fact somebody else has similar Problems: After working on other things in the mean time I now figured out how to solve this Issue.

It was rather easy and all work is done in the JSP:

1. Use Rich Tree Node inside the Rich Tree Tag
2. Use the ajaxSubmitSelection and reRender Attributes of the TreeNode
3. Wrap the Part of the Page, which should be rerendered in a `<a4j:outputPanel/>` and set its Attribute ajaxRendered to "true"
4. Ensure that the values of the id-Attribute of the `<a4j:outputPanel/>` and the reRender-attribute of the TreeNode are the same.

Hope this helps others with similar Problems,

Daniel